# Transform data from columns to rows on plsql oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with two columns for each month, like this

**table1:**

```
_____________________________________________________________________
|item  |  jan_p    |   jan_r   |   feb_p    |   feb_r   |   commpany|           
|______|___________|___________|____________|___________|____________
|1294  |  1234232  |  2323322  |   1242122  |   532323  |   E987    |
|______|___________|___________|____________|___________|___________|
```

I need to transfer the data to a new, more normalised table something like this:

**table2:**

```
________________________________________________
| item  | month | cost_p  |  cost_r |  company |
|_______|_______|_________|_________|__________|
| 1294  |   1   |1234232  |  2323322|    E987  |
| 1295  |   2   |1242122  |  532323 |    E987  |
|_______|_______|_________|_________|__________|
```

see image https://ibb.co/cDM91Q

I coded a loop iterating over the first table with a nested loop to insert a row for each month like this:

```
for reg in (select * from table1) loop
    for x in 1..12 loop
        case x
           when 1 then
              insert into table2(..., mes , ...) values(... , x, ...)
           when 2 then
              insert into table2(..., mes , ...) values(... , x, ...)
```

This is working but I just wanted to know if there is another way to achieve the same outcome.

Comment: please edit your question and use only english language, or post your question here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: no sabe nada de plsql cierto?

Answer (score 0):

> "I just wanted to know if there is another way to achieve this "

Yes there is. This is an ideal use case for the INSERT ALL syntax.

```
insert all
    into table2 (item, month, cost_p, cost_r, commpany )
        values (item, 1, jan_p, jan_r, commpany)
    into table2 (item, month, cost_p, cost_r, commpany )
        values (item, 2, feb_p, feb_r, commpany)
    into table2 (item, month, cost_p, cost_r, commpany )
        values (item, 3, mar_p, mar_r, commpany)
    into table2 (item, month, cost_p, cost_r, commpany )
        values (item, 4, apr_p, apr_r, commpany)
    into table2 (item, month, cost_p, cost_r, commpany )
        values (item, 5, may_p, may_r, commpany)
    into table2 (item, month, cost_p, cost_r, commpany )
        values (item, 6, jun_p, jun_r, commpany)
    ....
select * from table1
/
```

Multi-table inserts allow us to do some really neat things but still using set operations. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604).

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use pivot/unpivot functions? I don't use these but I think it solves your task.

*The Oracle PIVOT clause allows you to write a cross-tabulation query starting in Oracle 11g. This means that you can aggregate your results and rotate rows into columns.*

PS I have remembered Tom Kite solved it former.
Plese look at: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:31263576751669#76663048528720